# Why can't I call function from inside chrome.downloads.onChanged?

Tags: javascript, this, listener, typeerror

I'm creating an extension in chrome for the first time (I'm not a web, or javascript developer).  I'm adding onto a codebase that is in an older version of javascript that I've never used (Once I'm at a computer with that codebase, I'll tag which version it is, but I can't remember).

I have a class called DownloadManager, and inside of it I am calling [chrome.downloads.onChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged), and within it, I call another function inside of the class, but it can't recognize the class (I think that's the issue).

```
// Class named DownloadManager
function DownloadManager(someData) {

    this._myData = someData;

    // function that does a thing, and tests run successfully
    this.doAThing = function(someData) {
        // Code in here that we assume works, and there's no issues.
    }

    if(chrome.downloads) {
        chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
            // Error here
            this.doAThing(delta.data);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is on the `this.doAThing(this._myData);` line.  The error is `Error in event handler for downloads.onChanged: TypeError: Cannot read property 'doAThing' of null at <URL>`.

I'm assuming it's a scoping issue, and `this.` doesn't mean anything there, and it can't access `doAThing` there.  I'm certain that the argument taken in is of the same type as the function declared above.

I'll add more data when I'm back in that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your event handler for `chrome.downloads.onChanged` the `this` keyword now has a different context than `this` inside the `DownloadManager`. It might make sense that since you defined the event handler within the `downloadManager` that you could share the variable, but that just happens to be a coincidence of "where the code was defined vs where the code is invoked from".

You could probably get away with assigning `this` to a variable in the main scope:

```
function DownloadManager(someData) {
    this.doAThing = function(someData) {
        // Code in here that we assume works, and there's no issues.
    }

    window.myScope = this;

    if(chrome.downloads) {
        chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
            // Error here
            window.myScope.doAThing(delta.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since they're both inside of the class DownloadManager, I would have thought that ```this``` would point to the same object (obviously I'm wrong).  However, the ```var that = this;``` either where you put it, or inside the if statement returns the same error.  I know this is hard to troubleshoot without more data, and I'll get more in the question soon.  Thanks

Comment: You defined an event handler and it gets executed in a completely different place. Perhaps try catching this keyword outside of the download manager. I made a mistake including it inside. Or try doing `window.someVariable = this`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Looking at this further if you wanted to access the `doAThing` function (without caching this in the window object) you should define it outside of the `DownloadManager` class.